# Migrating old aws instance to current generation EC2 instance

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to change my instance type from old generation which uses paravirtual virtualization to HVM (current generation instance), I am following this forum to do stuff, [from AWS forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=648055). This cloning of an instance takes too much time and If I take a image from a running instance, I am not able to connect to the new instance which is created from that image. ssh fails (connection refused).

(With a new server- for testing) if I tried to detach the attached volumes, except leaving the root and clone, it starts and works, after that I could attach any volume that needs to be attached.

Answer (score 0):

Check the partition/volume mount points keep same names for mount points as it is defined in fstab of server so it will try to locate or read the same partition while boot

Example: /dev/xvdb  or /dev/xvda

Also use same key used for old server, new key may not work

Comment: i tried that, i took my paravirtual root volume and attached to hvm's root volume, the instance started and shut down in seconds.

Comment: check the on boot logs by right click on instance and get system logs, this will give an idea for reason instance is failing to start or restarting